# Jaxb - Custom HashMap mapping

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
<mapdata>
  <media1>
    <name>media1</name>
    <items>
      <key>1</key>
      <width>100</width>
      <height>150</height>
    </items>
    <items>
      <key>2</key>
      <width>100</width>
      <height>150</height>
    </items>
  </media1>
  <media2>
    <name>media2</name>
    <items>
      <key>1</key>
      <width>100</width>
      <height>150</height>
    </items>
  </media2>
</mapdata>
```

I want to convert above xml to below hashMap object using JaxB. Please help me on this.

```
public class MapData{
    protected Map<String, Media> mapdata;

}

public class Media {

    private String name;

    private List<MediaDetail> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<MediaDetail> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<MediaDetail> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Media grow like media1,media2,media3 etc .. Because of the unpredictable tags of media tag . I am not able detect using tag name . I need to map like media tag as key and maintain the detail as the value object which involves name and items list . Please let me know is it possible to achieve.

Comment: I dont have xsd . No

Answer (score 0):

Create xsd for you from your xml, through online sources like [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html).

Now you can use [this](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/) to generate pojo. Jaxb generate pojos on its own, later you can create the class the way you want getting fields and then setting to fields you want to. If you are using maven there are other ways available to create pojo instead of using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy to do so. You will probably use some `MapAdapter` or other type of adapter.

You will need to make changes to your `.java` classes. Putting some annotations.

And even you will need to change your `xml` a little bit.

Still I think you can find everything you need in [this](https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-javautilmap) article.

Good luck.